# I'm encountering an issue in React Native CLI where an error occurs whenever I navigate to the login screen

Tags: android, react-native, android-relativelayout, react-native-cli, android-splashscreen

This problem started after I added a splash screen. Initially, the splash screen appears as intended when the app is launched. However, the problem arises when I attempt to transition from the splash screen to the login screen. At this point, an error occurs, preventing the navigation. Attached are screenshots of the error messages and the contents of my launch_screen.xml file for further insight. My Splash Screen name is screen.png

[image: Error I am getting]

[image: launch_screen.xml]

I followed this installation process.
https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen